# Use Google Cloud Storage for hosting private Gradle dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle, google-cloud-storage

I had this setup before with AWS S3 and was curious if it is possible with Google Cloud Storage as well.  I'd like to be to publish and pulldown my java dependencies from a private bucket.

Originally only required setting up the right permissions on the bucket and then inserting the following into my `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 's3://some-bucket'
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey 'PUBLIC_KEY'
            secretKey 'PRIVATE_KEY'
        }
    }
}
```

Is this functionality possible with Google Cloud Storage (I'm fairly new to using it vs AWS)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is [supported](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/repository_types.html#sub:gcs_configuration_properties).